# ROS param KeyError

Tags: ros

I started learn ROS. I try to read data from launch file with param. but it gave me an error which I did not understand. Please help me. Here is the constructor:

```
def__init__(self,nodeName,goalx,goaly):
  rospy.init_node("node", anonymous="True")
  self.goalX = rospy.get_param("x1")
  self.goalY = rospy.get_param("y1")
  self.pub = rospy.Publisher(nodeName + '/cmd_vel',Twist,queue_size=10)
  self.sub = rospy.Subscriber(nodeName+"/odom",Odometry,callback=self.update_pose)
  self.odometry = Odometry()
  self.rate = rospy.Rate(10)


if __name__ == "__main__":
  nodeId = sys.argv[1]
  try:
      nodeName = "robot_"+nodeId
      x = Turtlebot(nodeName,0,0)
      x.move2goal()
      rospy.spin()
    ...
```

Launch File:

```
<param name="x1" type="int" value="4" />
<param name="y1" type="int" value="0" />
<param name="x2" type="int" value="5" />
<param name="y2" type="int" value="0" />


<node pkg="stage_ros" name="stageros" type="stageros" args="$(find beginner_tutorials)/world/worldfile.world" output="screen"/>



<!-- <node pkg="beginner_tutorials" name="rotate1" args="0"  type="projecttask2.py"/> -->
<node pkg="beginner_tutorials" name="rotate2"  args="1" type="projecttask2.py"
```

Error: KeyError('x1')

Answer (score 1):

You're running into this issue because of parameter namespacing. When using `rospy.get_param("x1")` you're checking pulling the param with respect to the *relative namespace*. This means you're actually checking for a param at `<node_namespace>/x1`. However in your node you're not declaring the param under your node; this means it's setup under the *global namespace*. You have two options to fix this. First, you can simply declare the params within your node's namespace like so:

```
<node pkg="stage_ros" name="stageros" type="stageros" args="$(find beginner_tutorials)/world/worldfile.world" output="screen">
    <param name="x1" type="int" value="4" />
    <param name="y1" type="int" value="0" />
    <param name="x2" type="int" value="5" />
    <param name="y2" type="int" value="0" />
<node/>
```

Secondly, you could fix the namespacing inside your node so that it pulls params from the global namespace like this:

```
def__init__(self,nodeName,goalx,goaly):
  rospy.init_node("node", anonymous="True")
  self.goalX = rospy.get_param("/x1")
  self.goalY = rospy.get_param("/y1")
```

For more information regarding namespaces you can check the [ros wiki page].[1](http://wiki.ros.org/roscpp/Overview/NodeHandles)

Comment: Thank you for answer, also sorry my answer a bit late.

Comment: @qwertyup667 If their solution answers your problem then please mark it as accepted :)